# Populating a pandas dataframe from an odd dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{'header_1': ['body_1', 'body_3', 'body_2'],
 'header_2': ['body_6', 'body_4', 'body_5'],
 'header_4': ['body_7', 'body_8'],
 'header_3': ['body_9'],
 'header_9': ['body_10'],
 'header_10': []}
```

I would like to come up with a dataframe like this:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | header   | body   |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | header_1 | body_1 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | header_1 | body_3 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | header_1 | body_2 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 4  | header_2 | body_6 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 5  | header_2 | body_4 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 6  | header_2 | body_5 |
+----+----------+--------+
| 7  | header_4 | body_7 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Where blank items (such as for the key `header_10` in the dict above) would receive a value of `None`. I have tried a number of varieties for `df.loc` such as:

```
for header_name, body_list in all_unique.items():
    for body_name in body_list:
        metadata.loc[metadata.index[-1]] = [header_name, body_name]
```

To no avail. Surely there must be a quick way in Pandas to append rows and autoincrement the index? Something similar to the SQL `INSERT INTO` statement only using pythonic code?

Comment: What if you just transformed your dictionary into something pandas could handle before hand?

Comment: That would be inefficient don't you think? It would introduce additional code...

Comment: More inefficient than attempting to reallocate the entire dataframe at every step? Because that's what appending to it will do.

Comment: For comparison, you have the dictionary, which is a data structure that is specifically designed to be mutated efficiently. More code does not mean less efficient code.

Comment: @W-B I would post that answer again. It is precisely what I needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dict comprehension for add `None`s for empty lists and then flatten for list of tuples:

```
d = {'header_1': ['body_1', 'body_3', 'body_2'],
 'header_2': ['body_6', 'body_4', 'body_5'],
 'header_4': ['body_7', 'body_8'],
 'header_3': ['body_9'],
 'header_9': ['body_10'],
 'header_10': []}

d = {k: v if bool(v) else [None] for k, v in d.items()}
data = [(k, y) for k, v in d.items() for y in v]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['a','b'])
print (df)
            a        b
0    header_1   body_1
1    header_1   body_3
2    header_1   body_2
3    header_2   body_6
4    header_2   body_4
5    header_2   body_5
6    header_4   body_7
7    header_4   body_8
8    header_3   body_9
9    header_9  body_10
10  header_10     None
```

Another solution:

```
data = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if bool(v):
        for y in v:
            data.append((k, y))
    else:
        data.append((k, None))


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['a','b'])
print (df)
            a        b
0    header_1   body_1
1    header_1   body_3
2    header_1   body_2
3    header_2   body_6
4    header_2   body_4
5    header_2   body_5
6    header_4   body_7
7    header_4   body_8
8    header_3   body_9
9    header_9  body_10
10  header_10     None
```

Comment: May I borrow your setting up for `d` ?

Comment: Very nice/creative answer. You can also use `if v` instead of `if bool(v)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53218931/7964527) problem again

Borrow Jez's setting up for your `d`

```
d = {k: v if bool(v) else [None] for k, v in d.items()}
```

1st convert your dict into dataframe

```
df=pd.Series(d).reset_index()
df.columns
Out[204]: Index(['index', 0], dtype='object')
```

---

Then using this function in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7964527)

```
yourdf=unnesting(df,[0])
yourdf
Out[208]: 
         0      index
0   body_1   header_1
0   body_3   header_1
0   body_2   header_1
1   body_6   header_2
1   body_4   header_2
1   body_5   header_2
2   body_7   header_4
2   body_8   header_4
3   body_9   header_3
4  body_10   header_9
5     None  header_10
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```

Comment: @jezrael ok let me delete my answer

Comment: I think this answer is still valuable as it shows an alternate approach. But I do prefer @jezrael's method since it requires less lines of code

Comment: @user32882 no worry , his answer is better for sure

Answer (score 2):

If the dataset is too big, this solution would be slow, but it should still work.

```
for key in data.keys():
    vals= data[key]
    # Create temp df with data from a single key
    t_df = pd.DataFrame({'header':[key]*len(vals),'body':vals})

    # Append it to your full dataframe.
    df = df.append(t_df)
```